# Showing that a given function is continuous at all irrational points and discontinuous at all rational points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, solution-verification

So, here's the problem:

Let $(r_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, define a function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n} & x = r_n \\
      0 & x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \\
       \end{cases}$$

Prove that the function is continuous at all irrational points and discontinuous at all rational points.

---

Proof Attempt:

So, let $f$ be as defined in the problem. We want to show that this is discontinuous at every rational point. Let $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and suppose that $f$ is continuous at $a$. Then, define a sequence $(z_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as follows:

1. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |z_n-a| < \frac{1}{n}$
2. $z_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

In other words, this is an irrational sequence that converges to $a$. We can create the sequence above because every interval $(a-\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n})$ will contain at least one irrational. However, we now consider:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0 \neq f(a)$$

where $f(a) \neq 0$ because $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}: a = r_N$ and therefore, that $f(a) = \frac{1}{N}$. So, this contradicts the continuity of $f$ at $x = a$. Hence, $f$ is discontinuous at $x = a$ and, therefore, discontinuous at every rational number.

Now, let $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Suppose that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$. Then, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq f(a)$. So, by definition:

$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall \delta >0: \exists x \in \mathbb{R}: |x-a| < \delta \land |f(x)| \geq \epsilon$

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$ be as given by the predicate above. Firstly, realize that the $x$ whose existence is being postulated has to be rational. Otherwise, we would get $0 \geq \epsilon > 0$ and that is impossible.

Define a sequence $(z_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as follows:

1. Pick $z_1$ so that $|z_1-a| < 1$ and $|f(z_1)| \geq \epsilon$ and $z_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$.
2. Once $z_n$ has been picked, define $z_{n+1}$ so that $|z_{n+1}-a| < \delta$. We will pick $\delta < \min \{\frac{1}{n+1}, |z_n-a|\}$.
3. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: z_n \in \mathbb{Q}$
4. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |f(z_n)| \geq \epsilon$

This is going to be a rational sequence that converges to $a$. Now, the idea here is that every term of this sequence appears in the enumeration of the rationals $(r_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

In particular, this sequence $(z_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is going to be rearranged in this enumeration and, more importantly, we can construct a subsequence of the enumeration from the terms of our sequence above. Now, this subsequence can be proven to converge to $a$ (just prove that rearranging the terms of a convergent sequence does not affect the convergence of the sequence). However, we now have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(r_{n_k}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{n_k} = 0$$

which contradicts the fact that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ (it, in fact, contradicts the fact that $(z_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ was specifically chosen so that $|f(z_n)| \geq \epsilon$). Hence, it follows that $f$ is continuous at $a$ and, therefore, at all irrational numbers. $\Box$

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your title and question.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I've fixed it

Comment: Bump, I would still like feedback on my solution haha

Comment: @Abhi FYI, [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function#Properties) has proofs for both parts of your question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan But I want to know if my argument is correct or not

Comment: I'm still open to having someone look over my proofs for both parts. So, I guess I'm almost completely fine with how my first part looks. I'm just not so confident about my proof of the continuity of $f$ at every irrational.

Comment: Your argument looks correct to me (after you pointed out the part I had overlooked). The way it is laid out is confusing, though. You should work on improving clarity.

Comment: Oh dang that's really nice, thank you so much. Yes, I'll work on improving clarity as much as possible, sorry